# temporal autocorrelation and perfect fit in glmm

Tags: mixed-models, autoregressive-models, autocorrelation, glmmtmb

I get some troubles with temporal autocorrelation and the way to implement it in glmm.
Here (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html), with an autoregressive process (AR1), they fit time series with one point by time step.
However, when I am doing that I get surprisingly high R², with simulated data and with empirical data,for example:

```
>library(glmmTMB)
>library(MASS)
>library(data.table)
>myfile <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/f-duchenne/data_for_test/master/data_for_test.txt"
>dat<- fread(myfile)
>dat$Annee=numFactor(dat$Annee)
>model <- glmmTMB(pheno_derivs2 ~ ratio+urban+ar1(Annee + 0 | species), data=dat)
>MuMIn::r.squaredGLMM(model)
            R2m R2c
[1,] 0.002107069   1
1-var(residuals(model))/var(dat$pheno_derivs2)
[1] 1
cor(dat$pheno_derivs2,predict(model))^2
[1] 1
```

How is it possible that the model fits perfectly the data while the fixed effect is far from overfitting ?

Is it normal that including the temporal autocorrelation process gives such R² and almost a perfect fit ? (largely due to the random part, fixed part often explains a small part of the variance in my data). Is the model still interpretable ?

Comment: sorry I missed a ` to end the code block.The questions are:
How is it possible that the model fits perfectly the data while the fixed effect is far from overfitting ? 

Is it normal that including the temporal autocorrelation process gives such R² and almost a perfect fit ? (largely due to the random part, fixed part often explains a small part of the variance in my data). Is the model still interpretable ?

Comment: You can always edit your question using the [edit button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63087809/edit) below it.